# How to get the int/size_t value from the iterator position of the minimum element in stl vector?

Tags: c++, stl

```
    std::vector<bool> reprVectors::encode(std::vector<float> input){
    std::vector<float> distance;
    for(size_t i=0;i<this->reprVectorsList.size();i++){
            distance.push_back(distBtw(input,this->reprVectorsList[i]));
    }
    std::vector<float>::iterator it= min_element(distance.begin(),distance.end());

    return this->reprVectorsList[it]->code;
}


float reprVectors::distBtw(std::vector<float> input, Node* node){
    double distance=0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<node->valuesInDim.size();i++){
        distance = distance +
                    pow((node->valuesInDim[i]-input[i]),2);
    }
    return (float)pow(distance,0.5);
}
```

it iterator gives me the minimum distance in the distance vector. 
How do I find the corresponding position in my reprVectorList?
how can I get an int/size_t value from it iterator returned by min_element?

Comment: You could consider making your vector contain a `struct { bool , float }` instead, and assembling some suitable operator overrides for it. That way you're only ever having to deal with a single vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
auto index = std::distance(distance.begin(), it);
```

This approach is favourable to performing arithmetic operations on iterators, since it is valid for all operator types.

Comment: This is a better solution than the one by MikMik, as it should support any iterator (and hence container).

Comment: @Rook exactly! Maybe I should have stated that in the answer.

Comment: @Rook: this is debatable. It will compile for every iterator type, but you'll get O(N) runtime for any iterator that do not support random access. As such, `-` can be used as a fail-safe, so that you reconsider the cost of the operation should the container type change. For example should it sit within a tight loop, you might prefer to maitain an additional variable (adjusted manually) to keep track of it rather than incur the big overhead.

Comment: @MatthieuM.it will compile *and* produce the expected results for valid iterator pairs, but yes, it hides away potential performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the "index" from an iterator like this:

```
size_t index = it - distance.begin();
```

Comment: +1, very slight nitpick: This is only allowable with a random access iterator (which however you have as it happens).

Comment: Note: the exact return type is `ptrdiff_t`, in general, because it might be negative.

Comment: @Damon: I consider this an advantage, as `std::distance` is O(N) for anything else than a random iterator.